# CS50 "Finance" problem, "Buy" function - Harvard CS50 course

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, cs50

Currently I am receiving the following errors for the "buy" section of the code. The code will run successfully and handles "buy" orders successfully, however check50 is returning these errors and I can't figure out why they are occurring or how to resolve them.

```
:( buy handles fractional, negative, and non-numeric shares
    application raised an exception (see the log for more details)
:( buy handles valid purchase
    expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found
```

Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def buy():
        """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")
    else:
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))

        if not symbol:
            return apology("Must provide ticker")


        stock = lookup(symbol.upper())

        if stock == None:
            return apology("Ticker does not exist")

        if shares < 1:
            return apology("Minimum purchase is 1 share")

        transaction_value = shares * stock["price"]

        user_id = session["user_id"]
        user_cash_db = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=user_id)
        user_cash = user_cash_db[0]["cash"]

        if user_cash < transaction_value:
            return apology("Not enough funds available")

        uptd_cash = user_cash - transaction_value

        # update the SQL database
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", uptd_cash, user_id)

        date = datetime.datetime.now()

        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?,                ?, ?)", user_id, stock["symbol"], shares, stock["price"], date)

        flash("Bought!")

        # redirect to main page
        return redirect("/")
```

And the HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

  {% block title %}
    Buy
  {% endblock %}

  {% block main %}
    <h1>Buy</h1>
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="symbol"     placeholder="Ticker" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="shares"                                placeholder="Shares" type="number">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>
   {% endblock %}
```

I have tried using the `isdigit()` method instead of forcing the shared variable to be an `int`, but this creates a conflict when ensuring the value of the shares is an `int` which is greater than 0 which breaks the code.

Comment: Your question mentions a log, so where is it?  That might even tell you the exact input that's causing problems.

Comment: When I run the code, as far as I can tell, all the desired functions I want it to perform (i.e. reject the purchase if insufficient funds, reject input if number of shares less than 1 or as fractions, and successfully complete the purchase if the Ticker and, no. of shares and sufficient funds are all correct). So I actually can't see the exception error that the check50 error code refers to

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: What will happen in your code if the user enters "abc" instead of a number?

Comment: When a user tries entering letters, they will not type on screen - only numbers will appear when typed

Answer (score 0):

In app.py use "usd()" function when you pass share price or total price to "render_template()" and in index.html use {{ value | usd}} format to show price of share and total price of share (As suggested in Hints of finance PSet)

Comment: I see that hint now in the problem set notes, thank you! Could you explain where to use the usd() function in the app.py code? Do you mean to include it like this:  usd(return render_template("buy.html"))

Comment: No do it like this 
For def index():   render_template("index.html", shares=share_list, cash=usd(b_c), grand=usd(g_t))   
For def quote():   return render_template("quoted.html", name=qouted["name"], price=usd(qouted["price"]), symbol=qouted["symbol"])

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer. My code:

index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Shares</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">TOTAL VALUE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for stock in stocks %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ stock.symbol }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.total_shares }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.price | usd }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (stock.price * stock.total_shares) | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <td colspan="4" align="right">Cash</td>
                    <td>{{ cash }}</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <td colspan="4" align="right">Total Value</td>
                    <td>{{ total_value }}</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py

index function:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    user_id = session["user_id"]

    # Fetch user's stock portfolio
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) as total_shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY symbol HAVING total_shares > 0", user_id)
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)[0]["cash"]

    # Initial variables for total values
    total_value = cash
    grand_total = cash

    for stock in stocks:
        quote = lookup(stock["symbol"])
        stock["name"] = quote["name"]
        stock["price"] = quote["price"]
        stock["value"] = stock["price"] * stock["total_shares"]
        total_value += stock["value"]
        grand_total += stock["value"]

    return render_template("index.html", stocks=stocks, cash=usd(cash), total_value=usd(total_value), grand_total=usd(grand_total))
```

Buy function:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get user inputs from the form
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
        shares = request.form.get("shares")

        # Validate inputs
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Must give Symbol")
        elif not shares or not shares.isdigit() or int(shares) <= 0:
            return apology("Shares must be a positive integer")

        # Lookup stock information
        stock = lookup(symbol)
        if stock is None:
            return apology("Symbol does not exist")

        # Calculate transaction value
        transaction_value = int(shares) * stock["price"]

        # Get user information
        user_id = session["user_id"]
        user_cash_db = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
        user_cash = user_cash_db[0]["cash"]

        # Check if the user can afford the transaction
        if user_cash < transaction_value:
            return apology("Not enough money")

        # Update user's cash
        update_cash = user_cash - transaction_value
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", update_cash, user_id)

        # Update transactions table
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        db.execute(
            "INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            user_id, stock["symbol"], shares, stock["price"], date
        )

        flash(f"Bought {shares} of {symbol} for {usd(transaction_value)}, Updated cash: {usd(update_cash)}")
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

Now let me explain, the main problem is here that our format we are using wrong format. We need to use `usd` function in order to make everything to work in right way. For example, look at carefully my index function and index.html. I am using here `usd` function for everything. I used `usd` function for cash, total_value and grand total. And also I used `usd` function in my index.html:

```
<td>{{ stock.price | usd }}</td>
<td>{{ (stock.price * stock.total_shares) | usd }}</td>
```

Your value should end with number.00 or any two numbers after any number.

Buy: you need to display transaction value and updated cash, after user bought a stock

```
flash(f"Bought {shares} of {symbol} for {usd(transaction_value)}, Updated cash: {usd(update_cash)}")
```

I have shared my code and explained everything as much as I can.